# django template's the for loop content is not beinhg displayed

Tags: python, for-loop, django-models, django-views, django-templates

```
return render(request, "auctions/close.html",{
"winners":Bid.objects.all()
        })
```

this is in my views.py ..

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

The winner for this item is

{% for winner in winners %}

<h2>{{winner.user}}</h2>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

and this is the close.html template. but here the for loop is not working....
can anybody tell me what is wrong here...

Comment: what do you mean here "for loop is not working" is it any error occurred, or you can see empty h2 tags on your page (it could be no objects at all in Bid ... print them Bid.objects.all() ... also be concrete what you want to print {{winner.user.username}})?

Comment: Could be many things: `Bid.objects.all()` could be empty. `Bid` may not have a `user` attribute, said `user` attribute may be empty, etc.. DO you even see the `The winner for this item is` -part?

Comment: no its not empty i checked. i want to print the user in the bid model.